# How to connect MySQL from remote server to RStudio in local machine

Tags: mysql, r

I am running this code to **connect MySQL(remote server-Linux) with RStudio (local machine-Windows)**.

```
library(RMySQL)
drv = dbDriver("MySQL")
mydb = dbConnect(drv,
                 host='1x2.x1.1xx.xx5',
                 dbname='mysql',
                 user='root',
                 pass='root',
                 port=3306)
```

The MySQL I am trying to connect to, exists in the remote server whose IP is '1x2.x1.1xx.xx5' and using the **default port = 3306**

Got this error -

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '1x2.x1.1xx.xx5' (0)
```

After all this, I am not able to understand **how this piece of code would even work without even asking the username and password to the remote server**.

If I am doing something wrong or missing out on anything, please let me know. Thank You.

Comment: Just a guess, but shouldn't the 'user' and 'pass' have the username and password? Not 'root' (which is the name of a default admin user)

Comment: its the mysql username 'user' and password 'pass' not the server's

Comment: Also check remote server configuration if it allows for external connections. By default it is disabled due to security concerns.

Comment: how can i check this?

Comment: Check file /etc/mysql/my.cnf for bind-address = 127.0.0.1 If it's not commented than comment it with # and restart mysql server

Comment: server does not have this exact path directory (/etc/mysql/my.cnf). Rather when I ran SHOW VARIABLES in mysql, it shows bind_adress to be * . Does this mean it allows for external connections?

Comment: Also in the remote server there is no internet. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @xlax: Than you should have remote connection allowed. What do you mean that there is no internet?

Comment: For example ..on the server, I cannot run Yum Install... commands which requires internet. But the server getting connected using PuTTY.

Comment: Are you able to connect using a different database tool than R? There might be a firewall blocking traffic, as you also can't make outgoing connections. Did you set up the server yourself? A VM somewhere? You'll also have to allow incoming  traffic on port 3306, not just ssh port 22. And then you directly connect to the database and don't need your normal (system) username and password, just the db credentials.

Comment: I am able to connect via PuTTY. How can I make sure that there is no firewall blocking at all?

Comment: Running this "tstat -an | grep 3306 | grep -i listen" found out 3306 is listening.  However, When I tried this command - "telnet 1x2.x1.1xx.xx5 3306"  got this error - "Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connnect failed."  Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem. Are you using a firewall? Or maybe your vm provider (if using one) has some 'ingress rules' or similar blocking traffic to your vm? Without more information it is hard to debug. Can you describe the setup more?

Comment: I am new to the system, have to figure things out by myself. Checking the firewall settings it says - "Windows Firewall is not using the recommended settings to protect your computer" and throws error when tried to change.